# What is the purpose of adding と?

Tags: grammar

For example:

> 柔和{にゅうわ}な線{せん}で縁取{ふちど}られた宝石{ほうせき}のような瞳{ひとみ}に、**ほっそりとした**顎{あご}、綺麗{きれい}な鼻筋{はなすじ}。美人{びじん}っていう人{ひと}の条件{じょうけん}しっかりと備{ととの}えちゃってる。

What is the purpose of the と in ほっそりとした instead of just saying ほっそりした?

Also what's the difference the following two?

> 美人っていう人の条件しっかり**と**備えちゃってる
>
> 美人っていう人の条件**を**しっかり備えちゃってる

Thank you!

Comment: Edited the formatting of the question just to make it easier to read. Had to search a bit for ほっそりとした and for the difference between the two sentences.

Comment: Don't you think it sounds cooler with と in it?

Comment: Heh. I think it sounds more casual without と or を.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> 1.「Onomatopoeic Adverb + Verb/Verb Phrase」
>
> 2.「Onomatopoeic Adverb + **と** + Verb/Verb Phrase」

The difference between the two in meaning and nuance is fairly subtle and minimal and both are equally correct.

When 「と」 is added, it can sound *slightly* more formal and for that reason, it tends to be more often used in writing than in speaking.  The 「と」 places a small amount of emphasis on the onomatopoeic adverb as well.  Please note, however, that these are merely tendencies and are, by no means, rules.

> Also what's the difference the following two?
>
> 美人っていう人の条件しっかり**と**備えちゃってる
>
> 美人っていう人の条件**を**しっかり備えちゃってる

There is no difference in meaning -- none.  Both sound pretty informal because of the 「ちゃってる」 endings.  It just so happens that each entence omits one particle.

Needless to say, 「～～ちゃってる」 is the colloquial form of 「～～てしまっている」.

Extra:

(For those of you who did not know, we have a ***ton*** of onomatopoeic adverbs that are in the ***physical*** form of

> 「**Kana + small っ + kana + り**」＝「**〇っ〇り**」.

How many of these you can freely and actively use would be directly related to how natural your Japanese is.  We use a few of them on a daily basis.)

A good list can be found here: [http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~QM4H-IIM/k010502.htm](http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/%7EQM4H-IIM/k010502.htm)