# What does "fūtsu" mean?

Tags: katakana, adverbs, onomatopoeia, gemination

This is from [Yuki-onna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuki-onna):

> Mosaku no kao ni iki wo fu-tsu to fukikaketa.

The "fuutsu/fu-tsu" is written in katakana and is most likely an onomatopoeic word, related to breathing. It's not essential to the translation, but it's really bugging me.

Comment: Questions like this would be a little easier to answer if we could see the original Japanese.  For future questions, if you can't type it in, maybe you could take a picture? :-)

Answer (score 14):

This is either a typo or a "reado".

Trying to reconstruct the original sentence from your *rōmaji* version, I'm guessing it is

> 茂作の顔に息をフーッと吹きかけた

フーッと is listed in some dictionaries (e.g. WWWJDIC)

> **ふーっと**
> **フーッと**
> (adv,on-mim)
>
> *with a whiff; with a puff*

The ッ is small (compare ッ with ツ) and is geminating the following "t" sound. The romanization of the small *tsu* is done by doubling the following consonant, so *f­ūtto* (and not <s>*fūtsu to*</s>).

You're correct in assuming it's an onomatopoeia and it's usually used for the sound produced when breathing out (either forcefully, or with a sound).

By the way, there are other onomatopoeic words that follow this pattern. Either they are written in all hiragana, or in katakana with only the と in hiragana:

- じーっと or ジーッと
- ぼーっと or ボーッと

or more generally also

- ささっと or ササッと
- ぎゅっと or ギュッと
- etc.

(Here と is written in hiragana for its grammatical function — it is turning an onomatopoeic expression into a "*to*-adverb", see for example [What is the purpose of adding と?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24943/1628) and the linked questions listed over on that question under "Related".)