# 「スカッと．．．」Why is the last kana here in hiragana?

Tags: grammar, meaning, words, manga, kana-usage

I am attempting to read RAW manga for this first time, and I am encontering a varigated use of カタカナ and ひらがな in sentences that leaves me puzzled.

The whole sentence is: 「勉強しなくていいさし、悪者退治なんて**スカッと**しそうだし」。

From a quick Google search I believe the meaning of the bolded word is "refreshingly; w/ a sense of relief" (please correct me if I'm wrong). I am aware that it is commonplace for words to be inputted in カタカナ for emphasis, however I am unsure if the と here is intended to be included in the word (and is intentional/misprint), or is actually some grammar point I am unaware of.

Any answers would be appreciated!

Comment: This is mentioned in the answer to [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/28527/1628). I will close the question for now and hope this resolves your question. If not, please edit your question and explain what part you're still unsure about.