# Why is 「パッと」 part Katakana and part Hiragana?

Tags: words, etymology, onomatopoeia

I have run across this onomatopoeia twice now in music lyrics:

> [打上花火 by DAOKO × 米津玄師](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-tKVN2mAKRI)：
> 「パッと光って咲いた　花火を見てた」

> [GHOST by 星街すいせい](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKKar5SS29E)：
> 「パッと弾けた感情に」

Having seen this occur twice now, I felt it was safe to assume that this is not merely a stylistic choice made by the lyricists. This was reinforced when I looked it up [on Jisho](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%B1%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8), which lists the main spelling as パッと instead of パット or ぱっと.

From what I can remember, I have never seen another word spelled like this, with part of it being ひらがな and part of it being カタカナ. Or at the very least, if I have, this one feels particularly curious, since I have always figured that the small っ／ッ characters act as a fixed construct where they are modifiers of the following syllable's consonant; like they're attached. So, if anything, I would expect the word to be spelled ぱット or パっと, with the っ／ッ sharing the script of the succeeding character.

What's going on here? *Why* is it this way, or, *how* did it come to be this way?

Secondarily, are there any other words that share this characteristic?

Comment: @Angelos Ah! So, the っ is one of [these](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1462/36097), making it less like a `pah` sound and more like `pa!`—like a pop? That fits well with the cases I've heard it used.

Comment: @Angelos If you want to repost your comment as an answer I will gladly accept it, since I think it (at least, indirectly) answers basically all of my confusion by clarifying that it isn't so much one standalone word but in fact one+particle. I think I just need to go and review all the ways the と particle is used.

Comment: This is also answered [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/79974/1628). Also see my answer to [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28525/1628).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This と is essentially the same as in と言う or と思う. In this case it makes an adverb out of the small sound word before it. Similar examples include ギュッと and ボーッと.

Comment: Another case to study along this line; 私は、その答えにただただ唖然（あぜん）としていた。