# gemination orthography

Tags: orthography, numbers, gemination

In this sentence

> ミサイルは高【たか】さ100kmより低【ひく】い所【ところ】を東【ひがし】に750km飛【と】びました
> *The missile flew 750 kilometers east at a height lower than 100 kilometers.*

appearing here
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10013261541000/k10013261541000.html
the recording sounds like there is gemination between the end of ひゃく and the beginning of キロメートル.

What is the orthographically correct way of writing "100km"?

> ひゃっキロメートル

or possibly

> ひゃッキロメートル

Comment: I would expect it to be the former since the 促音 comes from 100, thus separating the two words, but I'm only guessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @Simon in the comments: since the gemination comes from the く in ひゃく, ひゃっ should be the natural choice when writing ひゃっキロ in kana and I would not be too surprised to see

> [100]{ひゃっ} [km]{キロメートル}

as *furigana* in a textbook. (That said, in all textbooks for beginners I could find, there actually seem to be no *furigana* at all — try to search the web for images with something like `単位 教科書`.)

Note that numbers are usually not written in *kana*, so one should not expect any reliable corpus data to confirm this — e.g. the Balanced Corpus of Contemporary Written Japanese has 0 hits for both ひゃっキロ and ひゃッキロ.

However, @a20 has found a paper titled "Morphology of numerical expressions in contemporary Japanese", where the pronunciation of numbers plus counters in written in kana and you can find the following:

> [image]

Also interesting is the following:

> [image]

which says that for 6 and 100 (which end in く), gemination essentially always occurs, but for 1 and 8 (which end in ち), there is some variation.

Comment: I think ひゃっキロメートル is a perfectly correct way to write this in kana in standard orthography (as long as there is a reason to write this in kana, of course).

Comment: Logically that makes sense. Googling also agrees, I found one result when using the Katakana version, but a lot when using the Hiragana version. I even found some article from Nara University which had this particular word as an example, among other interesting things: 現代日本語の数詞と助数詞 ー形態の整理と実態調査 http://repo.nara-u.ac.jp/modules/xoonips/download.php/AN00181569-19900300-1015.pdf?file_id=3658

Answer (score -2):

In response to the comment above...

*since the gemination comes from the く in ひゃく, ひゃっ is more sensible than ひゃッ*

I can add the following sentence found here

https://www.asahi.com/articles/ASN7F2QDMN76UPQJ009.html?iref=pc_extlink

長期休【ちょうきやす】みが来【く】るとホッとしたし、終【お】わりに近【ちか】づくと「また学校【がっこう】が始【はじ】まる」とつらかった

*I was relieved when the long vacation came, and when it was nearing the end, it was hard to think that school would start again.*

in which we see the following vocabulary item with two different gemination orthographies, according to Jim Breen's wwwjdic:

ホッとした from : ほっと(P); ホッと(P); ホっと (adv,vs) (1) (on-mim) with a feeling of relief; with a sigh of relief; (adv) (2) (on-mim) deeply (sigh)

In light of this example, it consequently appears hard to justify the statement that "gemination comes from" a word, or that any particular orthography is "more sensible." Perhaps responses should be based on objectifiable information, such as frequency of a word's or a spelling's occurrence or at least percentages of their acceptability as determined by polls.

Comment: In the example ッ belongs to the onomatopoeic part ホッ and と is written in hiragana, because と is used in its grammatical function of indicating a *to*-adverb (see [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28525/1628)). The Balanced Corpus of Contemporary Written Japanese has 501 hits for `ほっとした` and 260 hits for `ホッとした`, but 0 hits for `ホっとした`, so there is no ambiguity whether っ belongs to ほ or to と.

Comment: Since ひゃっキロ is not really standard orthography (numbers are usually written either as numerals 100 or in kanji), spelling frequency will not be able to help here — e.g. in the Balanced Corpus of Contemporary Written Japanese has 0 hits for both `ひゃっキロ` and `ひゃッキロ`, but I'm sure any poll will give the latter close to 0%.