# Are these counter readings correct?

Tags: readings, counters

Are these *furigana* correct?

> 多【おお】い日【ひ】で [1日]【いちにち】 に [10袋]【じっぷくろ】 以上【いじょう】出【で】ますので、約【やく】 [100]【ひゃく】 [kg]【キログラム】 程度【ていど】出【で】ます
>
> *On a typical day, we produce more than 10 bags (of bread crusts) a day, which is about 100 kg.*

I found the sentence here:

https://www.fnn.jp/articles/392036

Counters are challenging; I once asked a similar question here:

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/65186/31150

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but the subject of 10袋以上出る should be considered as 廃棄. So it means waste is more than 10 bags/day, which is roughly 100kg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- "100kg" is not ひゃくキログラム but **ひゃっ**キログラム (or just ひゃっキロ when there's no room for confusion). ひゃく becomes ひゃっ before the K and P consonants. Likewise, 100回 is ひゃっかい and 100本 is ひゃっぽん (but 100人 is ひゃくにん and 100円 is ひゃくえん).
- Prescriptively speaking, じっぷくろ is correct, but じゅっぷくろ is more common. じゅう becomes じゅっ/じっ before K and P.

Other furigana are correct.

Related:

- [Why is 1st floor written as ikkai いっかい?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40325/5010)
- [gemination orthography](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/90606/5010)
- [What is the proper pronunciation for 十分/１０分? じっぷん or じゅっぷん?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11213/5010)