# usage of と in this sentence

Tags: particle-と

> 戻ってくると、千波が我先に**と**駆け寄った。

once we came back, chinami was the first to run up to (us).

how does this sentence change without the と after 我先に? Doesn't seem to quotatitive or conditional.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This と is "the optional と" that attaches certain adverbs. In your case, dropping と does not change the meaning of the sentence.

See:

- [What role does と play in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36764/5010)
- [What is the purpose of adding と?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24943/5010)
- [What does adding と after an adverb do?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42163/5010)

我先に【われさきに】 is a set phrase meaning "striving to be the first". It does not necessarily mean Chinami was actually the first one.

Comment: 我先に doesn't explicitly have the adv-と/Adverb taking the 'to' particle classification. Does that mean anything, or does that label not really matter?

Comment: 我先に answers the question "how?" so it's an adverb here. I'm not sure what your concern is...

Comment: @charu You mean jisho.org? Perhaps it's just a mistake on the jisho's side. 我先に definitely takes と. [BCCWJ](http://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/en/) has 16 exmaple of 我先に (wihtout と) and 14 examples of 我先にと.

Comment: @macraf,  in other words, can any adverb take と, or are "adv-と" adverbs the only ones that can? It seems that edict/jisho mislabeled 我先に in this regard based on what naruto just pointed out