# Can って be used instead of と with the adverb function?

Tags: song-lyrics

```
メイクでも魅力あればキラキラって輝くんだ
```

This sentence is from the song "Like OOH-AHH" by Twice.

Is that キラキラって equivalent to キラキラと? If so, are they always interchangeable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is that キラキラって equivalent to キラキラと?

Yes. って is more colloquial.

> If so, are they always interchangeable?

No. After considering a number of examples, I think this type of って can be used in place of ["the optional と"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/49006/5010) only when the onomatopoeic adverb is related to a (usually strong) emission of sound, light, energy, etc. For example, you can say バーンって鳴る, ピカって光る, ブワーって飛び出す, パリンって割れる and so on, but you cannot say ぐっすりって眠る, しっかりって勉強する or ツルツルって滑る. (The level of acceptance may vary from person to person.)