# Are there any differences between だんだんと and だんだん?

Tags: word-choice

I found だんだんと in this sentence but I'm not sure how it's different from だんだん?

女は毎日働いたので、だんだんと元気がなくなっていました。

([Source](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-lessons/3-4-the-crane-of-gratitude/))

Comment: Not sure though,  but maybe because its onomatopoeia と has been used to mark it, like きらきらと

Comment: @APK Thank you, can you clarify? By "mark it", what is the "it" here?

Comment: By "it" I mean the onomatopoeia だんだん. I am still a beginner and cannot provide you with the difference between だんだん with と or without as of now. You may try to find similar answers on Stack exchange for using onomatopoeia with と) or you could wait for someone to answer your question. But I am certain that the usage of と is because だんだん is an onomatopoeia

Comment: @APK Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42163/what-does-adding-%E3%81%A8-after-an-adverb-do). It seems they add と after adverb just to stress the meaning of the adverb.