# はっきり and と - Why?

Tags: particle-と

Why does はっきり take particle と?  はっきり is already an adverb, and I don't understand how the particle contributes to the meaning in anyway, or how it even makes sense.

Comment: Lots of these XっXり type words take an optional と

Comment: Also related: [What role does と play in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36764/5010) / [usage of と in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/49003/5010/) / [What does adding と after an adverb do?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42163/5010)