# What's the difference between 「ゆっくりと...」and 「ゆっくりとして...」?

Tags: meaning, usage, particle-と, adverbs

Is there any difference in meaning? When would you use 「~として」 instead of  「~と」?

I have already looked [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24943/what-is-the-purpose-of-adding-%E3%81%A8/24947#24947) for usage regarding「~と」.

Comment: I'm compelled to post [ゆっくりしていってね！！！](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%82%86%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8A%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AD!!!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is actually **huge** as far as I am concerned.  That is unless you are looking at this question from a totally different angle than I am.

「ゆっくりと」 simply describes the manner in which an action is performed.  "Someone does something ***slowly***."  What that something is not mentioned or implied in 「ゆっくりと」, is it?  Basically, we only have an adverb here.  A verb or verb phrase would normally follow it.

「ゆっくりとして」 already contains a verb in it.  「し」 is the 連用形{れんようけい} (continuative form) of the verb 「する」.

「ゆっくり（と）する」 means "**to take one's time**", "**to spend time leisurely**", etc.  It is a full verb phrase on its own; 「ゆっくりと」 is not.

Needless to say, 「ゆっくりと**して**」 is the te-form of 「ゆっくりと**する**」; therefore, another verb (phrase) would naturally follow it.  You will hear/read sentences like:

「シカゴで[2-3日]{にさんにち}ゆっくりとして、それからカナダに入{はい}りたいと思{おも}っています。」

"I am thinking about spending a couple of days leisurely in Chicago and then entering Canada."