# What does と mean as in いろいろと?

Tags: particle-と

The context is the following sentence.

> 父が病気なものですから、**いろいろと**お金が必要なんです。

I have two questions.

1. What does と in the above sentence mean?
2. How should 「いろいろとお金が必要なんです」 be translated? Money is necessary in various ways? Money is necessary for various purposes?

Comment: Some onomatope words can optionally attach と or come with と built-in when used as adverbs.

Comment: I was going to link [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24943/what-is-the-purpose-of-adding-%e3%81%a8) earlier but I wasn't sure it was relevant since I didn't think いろいろ was an onomatopoeia. Maybe it is?

Comment: @user3856370 I'm pretty sure it's not. I think that, rather, most onomatopoeia are used adverbially, not the other way around. Pretty sure いろいろ（と）is just an adverb.

Comment: @Shurim I think so. Thank you for the link!